# Detecting complex urls in GWT

Tags: regex, gwt

I have been searching for a regex for detecting urls in a text so that I can replace them with hyperlinks. I achieve the same for normal urls like `www.facebook.com` or `https://google.com` but its failing in certain scenarios like `https://xyzSite.com/getUser.action?id=123&pwd=5`. How do you suggest that I can detect urls with parameters such as the above ones.

I am currently using the following regex :

`(((ftp|http|https)://)?[\\w@.\\-\\_]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}(:\\d{1,5})?(/[\\w#!:.?+=&%@!\\_\\-/]+)*)`

Comment: You might want to try wrapping https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js instead of writing your own (or maybe port it GWT; there's also https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-java but it uses some GWT-incompatible classes)

Comment: I would write use a library for this. GWT uses a slightly different regex syntax in Unit-Tests compared to production mode.

If you want to write a pattern at your own, you should use GWTTestCase and not Junit.

Comment: @Christian : Yes you are probably write but we are kind of using our own internal tool for unit testing so unit testing is not an issue. I am now generating the hyperlink-ed text using replaceAll itself something like the following which is right now working fine for me : 

`public static String insertAnchorsForURLs(String ans) {
  return ans.replaceAll("((https?|ftp|file)://)?[\\w@.\\-\\_]+\\.[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]", "<a target='_blank' href = \'$0\'>$0</a>");
 }`

Answer (score 0):

I found the following function solving my problem :

```
public static String insertAnchorsForURLs(String ans) {
        return ans.replaceAll("((https?|ftp|file)://)?[\\w@.\\-\\_]+\\.[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]", "<a target='_blank' href = \'$0\'>$0</a>");
    }
```

I have tested the following cases on this :

```
www.google.com
www.somesite.org.in
www.mysite.com/whatever.action
www.mysite.com/whatever.action?id=1&pwd=2
https://google.com
http://google.co.in
```